# What is the control used to show or hide a particular panel

Tags: c#, devexpress

hii,
I am a fresher in c#,Now i am using dev express control.Now in my screen i want a control(looks similar to navbargroup).I want this control button to work in sucha way that it should show and hide a panel while clicking on it like dropdown..Which control i need to use???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Devexpress,  but I would image in this case it's no different to the standard controls.

You would create a button and in the event handler of that button you would set the Visible property of the panel that you want to show/hide to true/false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Visible` property of your Panel in your `NavigationBarControl_Click` event

```
SomePanel.Visible=true; //if you want to show
SomePanel.Visible=false; //if you want to hide
```